# Process Address space with multi-core Systems UMA NUMA

Tags: multithreading, multicore, virtual-memory, numa, smp

I have a doubt with the concept of Process address space when involving multi core processor architectures, for the case when both Processors share a common physical address space (I guess this is what they call UMA).

So, if a 32 bit processor can access 4GB of address range, and any 32 bit process owns this space during its execution, how is it possible to have two different processes running on two cores...since I think both processors would have common processor address space. Will the processors address space be split into the number of processes. In case of threads, individual threads can run on individual processors becasue they lie in the same address space, but what in case of multiple processes.

What would be the case with NUMA.

Answer (score 1):

UMA ("Uniform Memory Access") and NUMA ("Non-Uniform Memory Access") refer to the performance of the memory from difference cores. With UMA the performance for different parts of memory is the same (ie. "uniform") and with NUMA different cores are different performance characteristics with different areas of memory.

This is unrelated to address space issues.

In a CPU there are two important address spaces: the physical address space and the virtual address space. The operating system creates a virtual address space for each process which maps to different parts of the physical address space. So a CPU with 4GB of physical memory might have multiple processes with a 32 bit address space, but with different bits of physical memory mapped for each process, at the same virtual address. For example, address 0x00400000 might be valid in both processes but map to an entirely different underlying physical memory address. Those processes might also share memory, for example operating system pages and shared libraries loaded at the same address might be backed by the same physical memory.

In smaller systems where there no virtual address spaces, then you assumption is correct: All software shares the same address space.

Comment: Also multiple processes still occupy the physical addresses (RAM) at the same time.